# How can gnu-screen windows be configured to inherit the same ssh-agent session from the terminal?

Tags: gnu-screen, ssh-agent, keychain

I want to link some passwordless SSH logins to some `screen` sessions, so that anytime a window is opened in the screen session the ssh-agent is inherited, but whenever I open a new window in screen, the ssh-agent reverts back to the main sessions settings.

This is what I'm attempting but it doesn't work:

Before I start the `screen` session, I run `` eval `ssh-agent` ``. This ensures that the main ssh-agent which is set via key-chain doesn't get passed on.

However when I run `screen` it reverts back to the main ssh-agent's settings, and even when I run `` eval `ssh-agent` `` again within that window, the settings don't carry on to the next window.

Is there some way to run an `ssh-agent` session that can be carried on to each new window within `screen`?

In sum, I think I need to select which `ssh-agent` I should use whenever I open a new terminal window. If I have a number of `ssh-agent` sessions running, is there a way to choose which one a newly opened terminal window, or even an existing terminal window should use?

Comment: At any time you should be able to set the environment to the current value for the ssh-agent socket, and have it apply to all newly created screen windows: Use shell command `screen -X setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK $SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

Answer (score 1):

Screen version 4.09.00 seems pretty limited here, unless I missed something in the manual. There does not appear to be an `update-environment` like tmux has. <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> lets you type in `setenv BLAH foo` to change the value the screen session holds and thereafter any new windows created. Maybe instead source in the changed agent settings via the shell `.` or `source` command, possibly via a little selector function of some sort, possibly also picking some default when your shell starts up?